# I am facing an error while installing Flutter

Tags: flutter, java-native-interface, flutter-doctor

I am facing an error while installing Flutter. How can I fix it?

While using:

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

I am facing an error like:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError
A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Android sdkmanager tool was found, but failed to run (C:\Users\Mahendra Koppula\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\cmdline-tools\latest\bin\sdkmanager.bat): "exited code 1".
Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK,
```

(It is also in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLxX8.jpg).)

Comment: It seems from the error is that the issue is with Java Runtime. Did you have java installed before installing the android SDK if yes then update to the newest probably if not you should try reinstalling since I installed without and jdk and android studio automatically added the necessary dependency for me

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs due to Java version. Install latest version of Java at your system and then set the java path at your system. then try to accept the android licenses .